# Embeded video won't load in Cartodb.js

Tags: carto

I have custom infowindows in my map that have embed youtube videos. When I'm working directly in cartodb online, everything loads perfectly.

Within the content section of my infowindow code, I have the following:
< iframe width="640" height="390" src="{{embed_link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> < /iframe>

I am trying to create a similar map using Cartodb.js (using the api from the Cartodb map I have created with the infowindows that are able to load the video), and the videos were loading fine for a while, but now they have stopped loading. Where the embeded video should be, there's just a blank grey box that says: "The file or directory could not be found."
Is there any reason why the videos might just stop loading when I create a map using Cartodb.js?

Two examples of the embed_link are: "//www.youtube.com/embed/HyCBk9XC2Eo?feature=player_detailpage" and "//www.youtube.com/embed/ZZAFYROf2mY?feature=player_detailpage"

Comment: can you give a few examples of the text in embed_link?

Comment: I pulled it straight from youtube, so two examples are: "//www.youtube.com/embed/HyCBk9XC2Eo?feature=player_detailpage" and "//www.youtube.com/embed/ZZAFYROf2mY?feature=player_detailpage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are opening the HTML directly from the file system and your embed links are like "//www.youtube.com/embed/HyCBk9XC2Eo?feature=player_detailpage" (notice they start with //) so when you open the html from the filesystem the browser tries to fetch file://www.youtube.com/embed/HyCBk9XC2Eo?feature=player_detailpage" (because file: is the procotol being used).

The solution for this is either use http in the embed urls or open the html using a local server (I personally use python -m SimpleHTTPServer), I tried your app in my local browser and the videos are shown

If this is not the case, please, ping me and I will take a further look.

Hope it helps